# Serialize from nested objects by means of the id

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Let's say I get, from my backend, the following JSON response for a `Game` object:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "date_game": "2017-08-30",
        "users": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "score": 50
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "score": 40
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "score": 18
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "score": 10
            }
```

I want to deserialize such an object using Retrofit. To do so, I have the following classes:

```
public class Game {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("date_game")
    private String date_game;
    @SerializedName("users")
    private List<PlayerInGame> liste_joueurs;


public class PlayerInGame {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private Player player;
    @SerializedName("score")
    private int score;

}

public class Player implements Serializable{

    @SerializedName("id")
    private long id;
    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("email")
}
```

My issue is that I want the `id` fields within the `users` tag to map to a `PlayerInGame.player.id` and not to `PlayerInGame.player`, but my current code fails to serialize as I would have expected.

**EDIT:** I wrote a custom serializer to handle `PlayerInGame` objects:

```
public class PlayerInGameDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<PlayerInGame>{

    @Override
    public PlayerInGame deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        Log.d("DEBUG", "IN DESERIALIZER");

        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

        int id = jsonObject.get("id").getAsInt();
        int score = jsonObject.get("score").getAsInt();

        Player player = Player.PlayerBuilder().withId(id).build();

        PlayerInGame pgame = new PlayerInGame(player, score);

        Log.d("PlayerInGame ID", Long.toString(pgame.getPlayer().getId()));
        Log.d("PlayerInGame SCORE", Integer.toString(pgame.getScore()));

        return pgame;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important parts of what you posted are

```
"users": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "score": 50
    },
    ...
]
```

and

```
@SerializedName("users")
private List<PlayerInGame> liste_joueurs;
```

Unless you go through the work of creating custom deserializers, your json format will require that your `PlayerInGame` class look like this:

```
public class PlayerInGame {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private int player;

    @SerializedName("score")
    private int score;
}
```

This is because the data type (in json) of the `"id"` field is an int. There's no automatic way for Retrofit to plug the `Player` java class in here.

If you absolutely must use the `Player` type here, you will need to implement a custom `JsonDeserializer<PlayerInGame>`, rather than relying on default deserialization. This could then manually read the `"id"` field and construct a `Player` object based on that id.

https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html